# dlopen for different flavors in android

Tags: android, c++, android-gradle-plugin

I have a native lib in my android project where it opens .so files.
My android app has two flavours and they have different application ids.
In my `.c`code I use `ldopen` like this:

```
handle  = dlopen("/data/data/<application.id>/lib/libffmpeg.so", RTLD_LAZY);
```

So it works only for one of flavors at a time.

I tried to fix it with `#ifdef` directive:

```
#ifdef STAGE
  handle  = dlopen("/data/data/<application.id.stage>/lib/libffmpeg.so", RTLD_LAZY);
#else
  handle  = dlopen("/data/data/<application.id>/lib/libffmpeg.so", RTLD_LAZY);
#endif
```

I'm trying to define STAGE in my `build.gradle` file but can't find a way to do this. 
Here is a task I use for building native ources:

```
task buildNative(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
    Properties properties = new Properties()
    properties.load(project.rootProject.file('myProject/local.properties').newDataInputStream())
    def ndkdir = properties.getProperty('ndk.dir', null)

    def command = "$ndkdir/ndk-build";
    if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
        script += '.cmd'
    }

    commandLine "$command",
            '-C', file('src/main/libs').absolutePath, // Change src/main/jni the relative path to your jni source
            '-j', Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors(),
            'all',
            'NDK_DEBUG=1',
            'APP_CFLAGS=-DSTAGE'
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn buildNative
}
```

Can someone suggest me how to do this ?

P.S. probably the question is really stupid or I'm trying to do it in completely wrong way. Sorry for that but I have really small experience in c/c++ so I have no idea what all these `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES`, `LOCAL_CFLAGS` etc. does.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a silly suggestion, but make sure you're doing

`ndk-build clean`

between invocations, because the make system may not detect changes in passed in compiler flags to rebuild the files.

And in case it really is that obvious, is there a reason you can't dynamically link to ffmpeg at build time and load it via the Java mechanism?